# I have a Post and Attachment relation. How do I create the Attachment BEFORE the Post is created

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, foreign-keys, associations

I have two models named Post and Attachment. I am directly uploading the attachment to amazon s3 using Fine-Uploader. Upon successful upload to s3 I send the media url of the uploaded file back to my client in a JSON object.

After the client receives the s3 URL I send an AJAX post request to my rails endpoint where ideally id like to create the attachment BEFORE the user actually submits the @post for creation.

Once the @attachment is created I then render the @attachment IDs back to the client in JSON format so that if/when the user submits the post I can then take the @post.id and update the @attachment post id field with the id of the @post.

This is so that if a user uploads attachments, but never submits the post, I can have a job that goes and deletes all the attachments that never got updated with a post id.

The problem that im experiencing is that whenever I try to create an attachment ( Attachment.create() ) the record creation gets rolled back.

I know that it is possible to implement this configuration because my mentor and the person who assigned me this issue is a code guru and has directed me to do it this way. The problem is that he is traveling overseas so I cannot contact him for help on this. I say that to express that I really appreciate any help you can offer but if your advice consists of departing from this method, I simply cannot. It is a must that I implement this way.

Any help getting this working is greatly appreciated.

```
[1] pry(main)> Attachment.create(description: 'ho ho ho', media_url: 'test.com') 
  (0.6ms)  BEGIN
  (0.8ms)  ROLLBACK
=> #<Attachment:0x007f96b8c547b0
 id: nil,
 post_id: nil,
 description: "ho ho ho",
 media_url: "test.com",
 created_at: nil,
 updated_at: nil>
```

here are all my models and migrations

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord

  has_many :attachments, :dependent => :destroy

end
```

and

```
class Attachment < ApplicationRecord

  belongs_to :post

end
```

The migrations look like this

```
class CreatePosts < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :posts do |t|
      t.references :categories
      t.string     :title, unique: true
      t.text       :body
      t.text       :tags, array: true, default: []
      t.string     :slug, unique: true
      t.string     :description
      t.string     :status
      t.boolean    :private_post, default: true

      t.timestamps
    end
    add_index :posts, :slug
    add_index :posts, :title
  end
end
```

and

```
class CreateAttachments < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :attachments do |t|
      t.references :post
      t.string :description
      t.string :media_url

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
```

end

Comment: Do you have validations in Attachment mode? Show the errors after create with `Attachment.create(description: 'ho ho ho', media_url: 'test.com').errors.full_messages`

Comment: ` [2] pry(main)> Attachment.create(description: 'ho ho ho', media_url: 'test.com').errors.full_messages
   (325.9ms)  BEGIN
   (39.1ms)  ROLLBACK
=> ["Post must exist"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Rails 5, whenever we define a belongs_to association, it is required to have the associated record present by default. You need to set `optional: true` argument to skip the validation presence.

```
class Attachment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :post, optional: true
end
```